# How to add not null constraint in seqeulize if records with null already exist?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I had a table.

I added a new column.

Even though I had set default value in sequelize model, those columns still ended up empty.

So I get error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "col_name" contains null values`

How do you populate new column with default values upon creation so not null constraint is not broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can update the values first:

```
update t
    set col_name = ?
    where col_name is null;
```

Then add the `not null` constraint.

Comment: I see, that's doable. But many places it seems to suggest default values are applied automatically and that doesn't happen for me. However, Still a solution. +1

Comment: @MuhammadUmer . . . I don't think it is sensible for the database to update the data when someone adds a `not null` constraint.  Changes to the data that don't start with `update`/`insert`/`delete` and a handful of other commands make me nervous.

Answer (score 2):

> Even though I had set default value in sequelize model

I suspect there is a discrepancy between the migration and model. To insert the column with a migration containing a default value use `defaultValue` in your migration.

The following is a working example:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('tests', 'new_column', {
      defaultValue: 'test',
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    })
  }
}
```

Before running `sequelize db:migrate`
[image]

After `sequelize db:migrate`:
[image]

The [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint) for the `options` object in `addColumn` is hard to find, it's listed for a different method

Comment: ok yea this works, but if i put function as a default value then it doesn't